# Cannot get name & email with sign in with Apple on real device

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

So I'm implementing sign in with Apple, everything goes well on the simulator, I request email, fullName scopes, the authenticate UI shows, and I can get the data, as images shown below:

[image]
[image]

But when testing on real device (iPadOS 13, iPad 2018), the UI didn't show (it does not asks for name and email on the UI), and I can't get the email, fullName from the response, and I can also confirm that the `authorizedScopes` are empty, I can only get the user identifier

[image]
[image]

I believe this is a bug and will file a radar, also posted a discussion on the Apple developer forum (but they usually won't approve my post, I don't know why)

If this is not a bug, can somebody tell me how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue, whats your radar number? It seems to be related to cached auth responses. If you go to "Settings > iCloud > Password & Security > Sign in With Apple" and delete the authorization, it works. But if you auth again, it fails with empty scopes.

Comment: @HansKnöchel Seems like this is more likely a feature instead of a "bug", haven't filed an open radar yet, but somebody answered my question on the Apple Developer Forum, check this link for more info: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121496.

Comment: @HansKnöchel Problem solved! See my answer

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Problem solved! tl;dr

**This is an expected behavior**

Answered by Apple Engineer
(Original post link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121496)

> Hi aslkdjalksdjasdasd,
>
> This behaves correctly, user info is only sent in the ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential upon initial user sign up. Subsequent
>   logins to your app using Sign In with Apple with the same account do
>   not share any user info and will only return a user identifier in the
>   ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential. It is recommened that you securely
>   cache the initial ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential containing the user
>   info until you can validate that an account has succesfully been
>   created on your server.
>
> Patrick

### 2019/12/15 Edit

This behavior is also documented on Apple's Sign in with Apple doc, check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple).

> Ensure that your app relays the credentials and user information to your app servers. 
>   ***The API collects this information and shares it with your app the first time the user logs in to the app using Sign in with Apple***. If the user then uses Sign in with Apple on another device, the API doesn't ask for the user’s name or email again. It collects the information again only if the user stops using Sign in with Apple and later reconnects to your app.

Comment: Hi, if the user already used sign in with apple and then our server return error cause our server detect the username length is didn't meet our condition and than our code didn't cache the user information. how can i solve this? without telling user to stop using apple id from setting page?
Thank you,

Comment: I deleted the app from the appleId.apple.com and start fresh. I do request for name and email scope, but only receive the email, the name is not real, it's an identifier. I do have a mechanism to store this the first time. But, not sure how to reset all of this.

Answer (score 33):

If someone fails in storing "user email", "first-name" first time, then he should follow the following steps:

*iPhone Settings -> Apple Id -> Password & Security -> Apple ID logins -> {YOUR APP} > Stop using Apple ID.*

Comment: Some text seem changed in iOS 14, on my phone the flow looks like this: Settings -> Apple ID (the very top row with your avatar image) -> Password & Security -> Apps using Apple ID -> {APP NAME or BUNDLE ID} > Stop using Apple ID

Comment: I successfully did `Stop using Apple ID` for my test account with my app, and removed the user from the database manually. But still I cannot force the app to go into the original flow and thus am unable to retrieve the email and fullName. This surprising default behaviour makes it difficult to develop and test :(

Comment: Found the answer as to why it was not working for me. I was using an old abandoned `apple_sign_in` package. Use the `sign_in_with_apple` package instead, and the proposed solutions will work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74671355/force-sign-up-with-app-flow-to-reappear-for-sign-in-with-apple-in-flutter-an/74671907#74671907

Answer (score 0):

Sign in with Apple supply JWT token, which can be encoded on https://jwt.io/ or using iOS swift JWT library.

after encoding it you could get the user's **email**.

Answer (score 0):

Useful notes, that I would like to know about the issue:

1. After first login `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` will have `email=nil`. To reset the state you need to go to settings and reset it in Password & Security page.
2. JWT token (`String(data: appleIDCredential.identityToken ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8)`) **always contains email**, so you could easily decode the payload and get it from there.
3. On **simulators**, the JWT token **doesn't contain email**. So, prefer testing on real device