# Apple login issue - name and email not found swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I am implementing iOS 13 Apple Login in my iOS app but I am not getting Name and Email as per documentation in ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate

Request Example

```
 let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
      let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
      request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

      let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
      authorizationController.delegate = self
      authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
      authorizationController.performRequests()



func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {


        print("User Id - \(appleIDCredential.user)")
        print("User Name - \(appleIDCredential.fullName?.description ?? "N/A")")
        print("User Email - \(appleIDCredential.email ?? "N/A")")
        print("Real User Status - \(appleIDCredential.realUserStatus.rawValue)")

        if let identityTokenData = appleIDCredential.identityToken,
            let identityTokenString = String(data: identityTokenData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Identity Token \(identityTokenString)")
            self.delegate?.didAppleLoggedInButtonPressed(identityTokenString)
        }

    }
}
```

Email and Name is not found

> User Name -  User Email - N/A

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121496

Comment: yes, looks like a bug for now: if set [.fullName, .email] it will return nil, but will work if set only one value.

Comment: Check this for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57702357/5167909

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this forum has your answer. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121496#379297

> This behaves correctly, user info is only sent in the ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential upon initial user sign up. Subsequent logins to your app using Sign In with Apple with the same account do not share any user info and will only return a user identifier in the ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential. It is recommened that you securely cache the initial ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential containing the user info until you can validate that an account has succesfully been created on your server.