# Force 'Sign up with <app>' flow to reappear for Sign in with Apple in Flutter and retrieve email and fullName

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, authentication, apple-sign-in

The first time I signed in with Apple in my app, I received the full `Create an account for <app> using your Apple ID` flow. However, I was not able to see and save the email and fullName fields.
In all subsequent logins after original sign up, only the `uid` is given by Apple. This is expected behaviour, see [Cannot get name & email with sign in with Apple on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545635/cannot-get-name-email-with-sign-in-with-apple-on-real-device)

```
{
    credential =     {
        authorizationCode = "<FlutterStandardTypedData: 0x28195d5a0>";
        authorizedScopes =         (
        );
        email = "<null>";
        fullName =         {
            familyName = "<null>";
            givenName = "<null>";
            middleName = "<null>";
            namePrefix = "<null>";
            nameSuffix = "<null>";
            nickname = "<null>";
        };
        identityToken = "<FlutterStandardTypedData: 0x28195d460>";
        realUserStatus = 2;
        state = "<null>";
        user = "my user code";
    };
    credentialType = ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential;
    status = authorized;
}
```

They advise to remove the app in my `Sign in with Apple` list and that it should force the original screen to show up again:

[image: screenshot of removing app]

Unfortunately, for this account it does not show the original login flow after this step, but just the regular Log in screen, for when you are a returning user.

Other steps I added:

- removing the record from the Authentication screen in the Users table in Firebase.
- disabling, deleting and re-enabling the Apple Sign in in Firebase
- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub cache repair`
- deleting the app from the test device, rebooting test device and rebuilding from Android Studio.
- removing and re-adding `Sign in with Apple` in XCode via `Runner -> Signing & Capabilities`
- logging in with my Google Sign in and then logging out so it clears my shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await preferences.clear();
```

Env info:

```
username@devicename appname % flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on macOS 12.6.1 21G217 darwin-x64, locale en-NL)
    • Flutter version 3.3.8 on channel stable at /Users/username/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 52b3dc25f6 (4 weeks ago), 2022-11-09 12:09:26 +0800
    • Engine revision 857bd6b74c
    • Dart version 2.18.4
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14B47b
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone X (mobile) • 79f8aa15db6582019ae695924b064c727bacb88f • ios            • iOS 15.6 19G71
    • macOS (desktop)   • macos                                    • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6.1 21G217 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome                                   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.121

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

Update:
By adding the following step to the above list, I am able to force the original login flow:

- Log out apple account on test device and do not keep any associated data (probably stored data in my keychain via iCloud)

However, when running fresh, still the email and fullName fields are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I used an old flutter library that did not support the logout feature correctly.
I used `apple_sign_in`, which has been abandoned.
That package referenced `the_apple_sign_in` as the successor. But this package is also out of date.
As of date of posting, the package to use is `sign_in_with_apple`. I used 4.2.0.
If you do this, then it is enough to trigger the original sign up flow just by removing the app in my `Sign in with Apple` list here (https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage).